# Updating Multiplb Objects/Rows in Parse Dashboard

Tags: parse-platform

Im new to parse.com. Is it possible to update multiple objects/rows in Parse dashboard? Something like running update query in dashboard?

```
Parse.Object.update({...some filter...}, {...some values...})
```

Thanks

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide?language=curl#jobs  this may help.

Answer (score 5):

There's no SQL-like `UPDATE` syntax.  You would need to query for and iterate through the results, making the changes to each object.  The `each` method is provided on a `Parse.Query` for processing every record that matches:

```js
var query = new Parse.Query("MyClass");
query.equalTo("someField", "someValue");
query.each(function(obj) {
  obj.set("otherField", "otherValue");
  return obj.save();
}).then(function() {
  // All objects updated.
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Is there a limit of 1000 on query.each like query.find??

Comment: There is no limit. The code runs in synchronous manner, but can you please explain the control flow